# In TFS 2015 is there a way to increase the dashboard limit for a team project?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Our team is running an instance of TFS 2015. The maximum number of dashboards per team project appears to be capped at 20 per project. I would like to create more since we are running all of our backlog under one team project.

Is there a way to increase this cap in TFS 2015? Does anyone know if update 2 or TFS 2017 increases this cap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TFS we can only create 20 dashboards per team. (Tested on TFS 2015 and 2017) and there isn't a way to modify the limits.

You have to delete an existing dashboard to create a new one once it reached 20.

I have submitted a [user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/20244784-customize-the-dashboard-limits-to-increase-or-redu) to request this feature, you can go an vote it up to achieve it in future.